# Execute function once at the beginning of an if statement within a while loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've been building a Raspberry Pi based robot which responds to voice commands with a heavily modified version of Jasper. It has a degree of autonomy using its ultrasonic range sensor and the RPi camera board. I've just figured out how to integrate a MaryTTS local server into my code in order to have the robot sound out phrases, chosen from a randomised list of phrases, every time a decision is made as to which direction it wants to go in.

Here's the logic I'm using for its autonomy at least, which is heavily borrowed from a pythonprogramming.net tutorial

```
def autonomy():

    no_problem = True


    while no_problem:
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('pigs s 4 1460')
        os.system('pigs s 27 1500')
        time.sleep(1)
        x = 0
        dist = snr(x)


        if dist > min_distance:
            excite_random()
            print dist
            robot.forward(180)

        else:
            robot.forward(0,0)
            time.sleep(1)
            confused_random()
            os.system('pigs s 4 1500')
            os.system('pigs s 27 500')
            time.sleep(1)
            x = 0
            left_dir = snr(x)
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('pigs s 4 1500')
            os.system('pigs s 27 2500')
            x = 0
            right_dir = snr(x)
            time.sleep(1)

            if left_dir > right_dir and left_dir > min_distance:
                robot.left(180,1)
                time.sleep(1)

            elif left_dir < right_dir and right_dir > min_distance:
                robot.right(180,1)

            else:
                robot.backward(180)
                time.sleep(2)
                rot_choices = [robot.right(180,1), robot.right(180,1)]
                random.choice(rot_choices)
                time.sleep(1)

            robot.backward(0)


try:            
    robot.backward(0)
    os.system('sudo pigpiod')
    os.system('pigs s 4 1460')
    os.system('pigs s 27 1500')
    time.sleep(1)
    autonomy()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sleep()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.cleanup()
        robot.forward(0,0)
```

Everything is running great and I have myself a talking robot but my question to you guys is this - as you can see in the following snippet

```
 if dist > min_distance:
            excite_random()
            print dist
            robot.forward(180)
```

I have an if statement within a while loop that executes a function I wrote, `excite_random()`, that has the robot utter an excitable phrase and then move forward continuously if the range sensor reads above the minimum distance. However, I'd like `excite_random` to only execute at the beginning of each loop, after the distance is evaluated, rather than continually executing over and over as the robot is moving forward.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I'd go about this? I've tried messing around with nested statements, nested loops and lambda functions to no avail. It seems that I've hit a bit of a wall and I'd really appreciate the help. Hey and also, if you need me to articulate the problem a little better then please say and I'm happy to go into further detail.

Comment: Does the function do anything besides make the robot squeel?

Comment: What would be wrong with putting `first=True` before `while no_problem:` then replacing `excite_random()` with `if first==True: excite_random(); first=False`?

Comment: Rhys, if tiba's answer, or any other, works then you should mark it accepted.

Comment: Wow you guys were right on the ball, thank you for being so prompt, Hey no problem Bill I'll mark tiba's answer as soon as I test it but it seems like the solution I was looking for. Hey and wwii, nope, it just chooses a phrase at random and sends a request to the local Marytts server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a flag that checks if it's the first time to execute the excite function or not. If it's the first, then execute, otherwise don't.

```
def autonomy():

    no_problem = True
    # Assign an initial value to the flag (True)
    excite_flag = True

    while no_problem:
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('pigs s 4 1460')
        os.system('pigs s 27 1500')
        time.sleep(1)
        x = 0
        dist = snr(x)


        if dist > min_distance:
            # If the flag is the initial value, then execute the excite function
            if excite_flag:
                # Excite function will be executed for the first time
                excite_random()
                # Now reverse the initial value (False) to stop the if condition from happening (being True),
                # until autonomy is called again
                excite_flag = False
            print dist
            robot.forward(180)
# Then the rest of the code
```

Comment: Hey there tiba, this looks to be exactly what I was looking for. I'll give it a shot within the next hour and let you know how it goes. Thank you for the swift response!

Comment: Alright, I ran the code and its exactly the solution I needed. I also added `excite_flag = True` after the else statement in order to reset the loop. That way excite_random is executed everytime the reading is above minimum. Fantastic.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not super clear on your intent, but my best guess is to use 2 while loops.

```
while no_problem:
    # get distance
    # squeal once
    while no_problem:
        # move forward
```

Comment: I'm afraid I've already tried nested while loops ddg and ran into the same problem, excite_random just get called on an infinite loop.